# Как пропустить ключ в массиве,?

Tags: php

```
sort($_SESSION['const'][?]['position']);
```

Под **?** понимается некое **ID**, которое уникальное. Как добиться результата?

Comment: Можно уточнить вопрос? Что вы хотите увидеть? Из чего?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю вам надо отсортировать массив при том пропустить какие то ключи, то могу предложить вариант

```
$unsort_keys = 'ID'; // Или строка или массив ключей для пропуска
array_walk($_SESSION['const'], function(&$item, $key, $sortable) use($unsort_keys){
    $unsort = is_array($unsort_keys) ? $unsort_keys: [$unsort_keys];
    if (!in_array($key, $unsort)) {
        sort($item[$sortable]);
    }

}, 'position');
```

Comment: Спасибо, этот вариант помог. А точнее только функция array_walk().

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас в массиве `$_SESSION['const']` всего один ключ, и он всегда произвольный, то можете испоьлзовать функции `current()`и `key()` для получения текущего значения или ключа массива. По умолчанию указатель текущего значения будет смотреть на этот единственный элемент

```
$const = current($_SESSION['const']);
$pos = $const['position'];
```

Answer (score -1):

Я понял так )

```
<?php

session_start();
$id=session_id();

$_SESSION["const"]='gqw';
$_SESSION["id"]=$id;
$_SESSION["position"]='fdsf';

$_SESSION["const"]["id"]["position"];
//print_r($_SESSION);
$delete_keys=array('id');
$arr = array_diff_key($_SESSION, array_flip($delete_keys));
print_r($arr);
session_destroy();

//или так

if(($key = array_search('$id',$_SESSION)) !== FALSE){

     unset($_SESSION[$key]);
}

    ?>
```

Comment: И как это решает вопрос?

Comment: @Walfter если вы не поняли вопрос, почему вы думаете что это его не решает?

Comment: @teran автор вопроса сортирует массив, и ему надо пропустить ключ... До конца вопроса я не понял, но удаления ключа части массива не могу понять чем решает вопрос